# On the sum of i.i.d. $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space.
Let $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be i.i.d. And let $g_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable that follows the standard normal distribution.

It is clear that $E(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|g_n|^2) = \infty$.
However, I wonder whether $E(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g_n|) = \infty$ or it is finite. If $E(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g_n|) < \infty$, then I want to know the threshold of $p \in (1, 2)$ suth that $E(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |g_n|^p) < \infty$.

Comment: Hint: $E \sum |g_n|=\sum E|g_n|
=\sum E|g_1|$.

Comment: Why is $E(|g_n|)$ a constant?

Comment: $(g_n)$ is given to be i.i.d.

Comment: Yep, one of the 'i's in i.i.d. means "identical."